# Executing stored procedure in Linked server inserts junk chars in null field

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am executing a stored procedure in a linked server using `sp_executesql`

if any one the parameters is null then,  it updates with some  junk chars

can anyone point me in right direction to resolve this.

we are executing the below command inside SQL Stored proc

```
.....       


Set @sSQL = 'Execute (''begin xxx_YYYYY_ADDRESS_PKG.ZZZ_ADDRESS_UPDATE_PROC(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); end;'','
+ Cast(@OPersonID as nVarchar) +',''' 
+ @OPrimaryFlag + ''',''' 
+ @OAddressType + ''',''' 
+ @OAddressLine1 + ''',''' 
+ @OAddressLine2 + ''',''' 
+ @OAddressLine3     + ''',''' 
+ @OAddressCity + ''',''' 
+ @OPostalCode + ''',''' 
+ @OCountry + ''',''' 
+ @OSNumber + ''',
@OErrorNo output,
@OErrorDescription output) AT ' + @LinkedServerName 

Exec sp_executesql @sSQL,N'@OErrorNo INT OUT, @OErrorDescription nVarchar(350)    OUT',@OErrorNo = @OErrorNo OUT,@OErrorDescription = @OErrorDescription OUT
```

If AddressLine2 or AddressLine 3 is passed as '' (empty string).

i am getting junk chars in Oracle like " `0(ŀ    绀¾"  or "绀¾` " <-- some junk chars

We have updated to latest oracle client too.. but nothing fixed this issue.

Comment: What is the data type on the Oracle side?

Comment: Hi Szymon, The data type is varchar on Oracle side